# Cocoa framework issue when archiving for iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm a beginner in iOS development and I recently added a framework using CocoaPods : it is SwiftyJSON.

When I archive the project in order to publish it on the Store there's a problem : how to include the Pods project containing SwiftyJSON's library ?

The error is : error with API file to heavy...

That's my project :

[image]

Comment: You don't need to include the source code.  The archive is archiving the compiled binary.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when something is red, it means that the project cannot find it anymore. Make sure that The reference to the framework is still pointing to the files.

Does your project build fine?

Also, under "Build Phases", make sure that the framework is listed under "Link Binary With Libraries". Here is a picture of that section:

http://images.revealapp.com/integration_guide/copy-library-bundle-resources.jpg

Some other suggestions from this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18493:

- Make sure you've updated to the latest java version.
- Disable bitcode
- Disable symbols
- Make sure your bundle identifier matches what is in your apple developer account.